# what's the best way to check log files for the same application deployed on multiple servers?

Tags: linux, logging

We have an application deployed on 9 servers. The application logs to a file, for example, myapp.log, so on each server, we have the same myapp.log file. Each time the traffic only hits one of those 9 servers and only updates the myapp.log on that server. So for troubleshooting, I need to log into all those 9 servers and check the myapp.log file for each server, which is extremely time consuming...So I am wondering if there is a better way to do that? Or, if there is a standard process to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`syslog` is default standard for logging on linux.
Write your logs into `syslog`, and then configure all 9 daemons that implement `syslog` protocol to transfer logs into machine where you want to read logs.